# How can I fix `cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time [E0499] second mutable borrow occurs here`?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a TCP connection where packets are coming as two byte packet length + variable length payload (less than 256 bytes). I am trying to first read the length part, then use it to read the payload.

```rust
pub struct Client {
    tcp_stream: TcpStream,
    packet_length_buf: [u8; 2],
    packet_buf: [u8; 256],
}

impl Client {

    pub fn new(tcp_stream_addr: &str) -> anyhow::Result<Self> {
        let tcp_stream = TcpStream::connect(tcp_stream_addr)?;
        tcp_stream.set_nodelay(true)?;
        tcp_stream.set_nonblocking(true)?;
        Ok(Self {
            tcp_stream,
            packet_length_buf: Default::default(),
            packet_buf: [0; 256],
        })
    }

    pub fn read(&mut self) -> anyhow::Result<&[u8]> {
        let packet_length = self.read_len()?;
        self.read_exact(&mut self.packet_buf[..packet_length])
    }

    fn read_len(&mut self) -> anyhow::Result<usize> {
        self.read_exact(&mut self.packet_length_buf)?;
        let packet_length = u16::from_be_bytes(self.packet_length_buf) as usize;
        Ok(packet_length)
    }

    fn read_exact(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> anyhow::Result<&[u8]> {
        loop {
            match self.tcp_stream.read_exact(buf) {
                Ok(_) | Err(_) => todo!(),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting following compile errors:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.packet_length_buf` as mutable more than once at a time
    |
100 |         self.read_exact(&mut self.packet_length_buf)?;
    |         ----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
    |         |    |          |
    |         |    |          second mutable borrow occurs here
    |         |    first borrow later used by call
    |         first mutable borrow occurs here
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
    |
100 |         self.read_exact(&mut self.packet_length_buf)?;
    |         ^^^^^----------^---------------------------^
    |         |    |          |
    |         |    |          first mutable borrow occurs here
    |         |    first borrow later used by call
    |         second mutable borrow occurs here
```

Same error is coming also at `self.read_exact(&mut self.packet_buf[..packet_length])`

How can I fix this issue? What am I missing?
How can I read two buffers sequentially in Rust without having borrow issues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand why the issue is triggered, but don't know how to solve it, or do you also want an explanation about why Rust complains about this issue?

Comment: I'd like to learn both. The answer below helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with a signature like `fn(x: &mut X, y: &mut Y)` the borrow checker is supposed to be able to prove that `x` and `y` cannot alias each other. This (in theory) enables a whole host of optimizations and can prevent a bunch of bugs. When you have a method

```
fn read_exact(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> anyhow::Result<&[u8]>
```

that you want to call like

```
self.read_exact(&mut self.packet_length_buf)?;
```

the borrow checker can't prove that. You're passing it a mutable reference to `self` *and* a mutable reference to `self.packet_length_buf`. They *could* alias each other, so Rust doesn't allow it.

To prove to Rust that they *don't* alias each other, you need to borrow the fields of `self` that you want to mutate separately. The most straight-forward way to do that is to use a free-standing function instead of a method:

```
fn read_exact<'buf>(stream: &mut TcpStream, buf: &'buf mut [u8]) -> anyhow::Result<&'buf [u8]> {
    loop {
        match stream.read_exact(buf) {
            Ok(_) | Err(_) => todo!(),
        }
    }
}
```

which you can call like

```
fn read_len(&mut self) -> anyhow::Result<usize> {
    read_exact(&mut self.tcp_stream, &mut self.packet_length_buf)?;
    let packet_length = u16::from_be_bytes(self.packet_length_buf) as usize;
    Ok(packet_length)
}
```

Because `self.tcp_stream` and `self.packet_length_buf` are borrowed separately, Rust can prove that they don't alias.